# What password do you use when your installing or delleting app?

Tags: software-installation, authentication

When I attempt to install software, I am prompted for a password.  What is this password?

[Software to be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEXPL.jpg)
[Password Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXgwe.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

To play multimedia files you need to install the codecs. In Ubuntu its as easy as:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Next, it prompts for a `password`. This `password` is the same password you used to login into your Ubuntu with.

Comment: Mods: Ignore the flag, i want to cancel it now beacuse i thought it was not answering, beacuse of the unneccesary part.

Answer (score 1):

This password (and most any password on your system) is going to be the same one used to log in.  The reason for this is to prevent unauthorized users from installing malicious software on your system.

By prompting you for your login password, the system ensures that only you or people who have your password can install software.

Comment: Thank you for helping me,Guy's but we have another problem please help me.why all my files, icon was gone after I update my software?

Comment: You'll need to ask a separate question for that.